# Xamarin : html page embeded in WebView doesn't execute js

Tags: javascript, android, html, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a new Android Xamarin Solution .
I want to embed an HTML page that execute js script in a WebView.
I added this html and this js page in  Android Assets.

[image]

```
MainPage.xaml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <Label Text="Start developing now" FontSize="Title" Padding="30,10,30,10"/>
        <Label Text="Make changes to your XAML file and save to see your UI update in the running app with XAML Hot Reload. Give it a try!" FontSize="16" Padding="30,0,30,0"/>
        <Label FontSize="16" Padding="30,24,30,0">
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <FormattedString.Spans>
                        <Span Text="Learn more at "/>
                        <Span Text="https://aka.ms/xamarin-quickstart" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    </FormattedString.Spans>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
        <WebView x:Name="webView" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 using Xamarin.Forms;
    
    namespace App1
    {
        public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
        {
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                webView.Source = "file:///android_asset/titi.html";
            }
        }
    }
```

titi.html

```
 <html>
    <body>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    
        <h1>Webview Test</h1>
        <br />
        Enter name: <input type="text" id="name">
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="button" onclick="javascript: displayName($('#name').val());">Test Button</button>
        <br />
        <p id="result">Result:</p>
        <script src="./titi.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

titi.js

```
function displayName(str) {
    try {
        $('#result').text($('#result').text() + " " + str);
    
    }
    catch (err) {
        log(err);
    }
}
```

The HTML page is correctly displayed but the js part is not executed when I click on button.

Could you help me to unblock the situation please?

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#local-html-content

Comment: Thank you but the cases in this doc are slighltly more simple than the case in my question. It doesn't show how to embed a custom HTML page with custom js .

Comment: Yes it does.  "Although the first page has been loaded, the WebView has no knowledge of where the HTML came from. That is a problem when dealing with pages that reference local resources. Examples of when that might happen include when local pages link to each other, a page makes use of a separate JavaScript file, or a page links to a CSS stylesheet."

Comment: thank you but unfortunately the instructions of this doc  are not precise enough to be applied

Comment: There are step by step instructions AND a complete sample project.  What more do you need?

Comment: if I try to adapt the sample , DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get(); raises a null exception but even if I replace this line by  htmlSource.BaseUrl = "file:///android_asset/"; it displays the html page without executing the js,  this is the issue of my question.

Comment: Hi, I tested your code at my side, It worked well. when I clicked the button It displayed. I used your code and changed nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if I don't use jquery in the js file.

```
 function displayName(str) {
     var result = document.querySelector('#result');
     result.innerHTML = str;
  }
```